# Cant filter dynamic query

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, dynamic

Hi i got question for the entity query. Please see my code

```
 var list = from table in db.USER_BETTINGS
                       where table.UserID == UserId
                       && table.UserID !="admin"
                           //&& table.WinningAfterRebate != 0m
                       && table.BettingTransactionTime >= fromDate &&
                         table.BettingTransactionTime <= toDAte
                       //&& table.WinningAfterRebate !=0m

                  //     orderby table.BettingTransactionNumber descending//table.BettingNumber descending//, table.BettingTransactionTime descending//
                       select table;

            if (loteryNumber != 0)
            {

              list=  list.Where(x => x.LotteryNumber == loteryNumber);
            }

            if (gameNum != 0)
            {

                list= list.Where(x => x.GameNumber == gameNum);
            }

            if (periodDate != "")
            {

               list= list.Where(x => x.PeriodDate == periodDate);
            }



            if (close.Equals("Y"))
            {

                list=  list.Where(w => w.WinningAfterRebate != 0m);
            }
            else
            {

                list= list.Where(x => x.WinningAfterRebate == 0);
            }
```

But the list not filtering , It return all record? Anyone got face this problem before?

Comment: It should filter if parameters are correct. We can't debug your code, so I am voting to close this.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri not working. if not i wont open this question. Ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some makeover in this code. You have unnecessarily used so many if condition, we need to get rid of that first. Change your query with the following.

```
var list =( from table in db.USER_BETTINGS
            where table.UserID == UserId
            && table.UserID !="admin"
            && table.BettingTransactionTime >= fromDate 
            && table.BettingTransactionTime <= toDAte
            && table.LotteryNumber == (loteryNumber != 0 ? loteryNumber : table.LotteryNumber)
            && table.GameNumber == (gameNum != 0 ? gameNum : table.GameNumber)
            && table.PeriodDate == (periodDate != string.Empty ? periodDate : table.PeriodDate )
            && (close.Equals("Y") ? table.WinningAfterRebate != 0 : table.WinningAfterRebate == 0)
            ).ToList();
```

Comment: @Welcome: I appreciate that it helped you and kindly don't use so many `if..else` condition and use **ternary operator** instead.